# android: creating a textfield display on the same activity with a ListActivity

Tags: java, android

I have an activity that pulls a String Array from xml and displays a ListActivity (the class extends ListActivity) and I'd like to know if it is possible to also display a textfield or textView below the list?

If so, what method should I research to do this? Have code samples?

Thanks!

CODE:

```
public class txchl extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String[] rmenu = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.root_menu);
    if (rmenu != null) {
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, rmenu));
    }
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Hello");
    setContentView(tv);
}
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    //
    if (position == 4 || position == 5) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity2.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("com.activity.Key", position);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    } else {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), txchl_hb.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("com.activity.Key", position);
        //myIntent.putExtra("com.activity.Dir", directives[position]);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a vertical `LinearLayout` that contains a `ListView` and a `TextView`

There is an example of what you want to achieve in the android reference:

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:paddingLeft="8dp"
         android:paddingRight="8dp">

     <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#00FF00"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

     <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#FF0000"
               android:text="No data"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have both objects listed in my layout.xml and am using the ListActivity, then calling the setContentView, however only the list is visible. I'll add the code to my OP.

Comment: The above code only displays the TextView if the ListView is empty. Not sure if that's what we're looking for here. You might want to try changing the android:id of that TextView to something other than "@id/android:empty".

Comment: The Text is showing up after editing the id. I now need to wory about it's display location and formatting. Thanks!

Comment: @BigFwoosh you're right. It even says so in the reference page (besides it's UGLY ;) I did not even notice that when I pasted it.

Comment: @bzo311 I'm glad it worked. Please feel free to edit the answer to match what you needed to. Sorry about that, I was too quick pasting the example!